# find a node in xml using Jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

Hi I am really new to Jquery and have a problem with my script , I want to access the 2nd 'heading' tag in my xml file using jquery .
this is my script so for but what I want to do is assign a vairiable to the 2nd value of heading .

```
 $(document).ready(function()
        {

             $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "task.xml",
               dataType: "xml",
               success: displayXml
            });

        function  displayXml(data){

          $(data).find("tasks").each(function() {

          var heading = $(this).find("heading").text();

          });
        } 

        }); // doc ready
```

this is my xml doc. What I am looking for is something like

name = $("heading",2).text();  the value being 'New Job'. Can anyone help me with this please ?

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <tasks>

                <heading>Home </heading>

                <heading>New Job </heading>

                <heading>System </heading>

        </tasks>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what are you looking for?

```
$("heading:eq(1)",data).text();
```

As you can see here in the doc http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/ `jQuery()` (same as `$()`) receives second parameter "context", in your case this will be `data` and jQuery will search in this context instead of your HTML/DOM.

Answer (score 1):

insomniac's reply is, I believe, not quite correct, because `:nth-child(2)` returns every other selector, not just the second.  The selector you need is `:eq(1)`.  This gets the second item to match the previous selector:

```
$(this).find('heading:eq(1)').text();
```

Note that `eq` uses 0-based indexing (i.e. the first item is 0, the second is 1, etc).

See the jQuery API for more information: http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/